# Using Wick's theorem on already normal-ordered functions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, operators, wick-theorem

The book [*Quantum Field Theory of Many Body systems* (X. G. Wen)](https://books.google.fr/books/about/Quantum_Field_Theory_of_Many_Body_System.html?id=FQpREAAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y) defines Wick's theorem as follows.

[image: Section 3.1 - QFT of Many-Body Systems (X. G. Wen)]

I would like to employ this definition to simplify the 4-operator product $$\hat{O}\;=\;a_p^\dagger a_q^\dagger a_r a_s$$ into a sum of two-operator products. However, as this operator is already normal ordered, the terms $W$ and $:W:$ are the same in the above expression, and therefore all other terms on the RHS would equal zero. Could someone kindly provide pointers on the correct implementation of [Wick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick%27s_theorem) in this case?

Comment: This feels like it may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to do that means you want to simplify a normal ordered operator? In any case a bit more context will make it much easier for us to give a helpful answer

Comment: @BySymmetry - Thanks! I am attempting to solve the problem of weakly interacting bosons, using mean field theory, presented in the same section of this reference book above. Within this approach, the 4-operator product is simplified to a sum of 2-operator product in the interaction Hamiltonian. I simply hope to understand and solve it for myself too. For reference, the Hamiltonian is of the form:

$H = \sum_k \; (\epsilon_k - \mu) a_k^\dagger a_k + \mathcal{V}^{-1}\;\frac{1}{2}\;\sum_{k,k',q}\;V_q\;a^\dagger_{k'-q}a^\dagger_{k+q}a_{k'}a_{k}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator is already normal-ordered and does not require any further simplification. Note that it annihilates the vacuum state. On the other hand, simplifying operator $a_s a_r a_q^\dagger a_p^\dagger$ could be a useful exercise.

Comment: Thanks! But would you happen to have a recommendation on how to simplify the product into pairs of $a^\dagger$ and $a$ operators - which happens to be the simplification I require?

Comment: I don't think you can simplify it any more - in general case. If some of the operators refer to the same state, then it could be simplified.

Comment: I see. As I've just appended to the question - I was attempting to simplify the weakly interacting boson system, with a Hamiltonian of the form 
$H = \sum_k \; (\epsilon_k - \mu) a_k^\dagger a_k + \mathcal{V}^{-1}\;\frac{1}{2}\;\sum_{k,k',q}\;V_q\;a^\dagger_{k'-q}a^\dagger_{k+q}a_{k'}a_{k}$. I am unfortunately not how the commutation relations would help me break this term down into a sum of 2-operator products, as the book prescribes.

Comment: I think the question here is not about the Wick's theorem, but about an *approximation* that might be used for weakly interacting bosons - I cannot say anything, as I do not have this book at hand. I suggest that you ask a new question outlining exactly your problem: the Hamiltonian that you are trying to simplify, the desired result, and how you have tried to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is already normal ordered, as you say, so there is no point in applying the normal ordering to it.
Now, I haven't studied the applications of QFT to many bodies, so I don't know what purpose Wick's theorem has in this book/area, but I don't *think* you should be using it to re-express an ordinary operator; i.e. istead of applying the formula you attach just apply the conmutation relations of the annihilation-creation operators to normal order it, thus deriving the factors you may or may'nt have. I only use Wick's theorem to go from time ordering from normal ordering, albeit my knowledge in the subject is very limited at present.
Of course, the two approaches are equivalent, but since you asked for pointers in applying it, I feel like you would get more familiar with it by working out the expression yourself rather than simply applying a *formula*.
Sorry for the lengthy -and subjective- answer, have a nice day :)